# What is the difference between filename=${1:-/etc/hosts} and filename=/etc/hosts?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, variable

What is the difference between `filename=${1:-/etc/hosts}` and `filename=/etc/hosts`?

For example:

```
filename=/etc/hosts

if [ -r "$filename" ] && [ -s "$filename" ]; then
    md5sum $filename
else
    echo "$filename cannot be processed"
fi
```

and

```
filename=${1:-/etc/hosts}

if [ -r "$filename" ] && [ -s "$filename" ]; then
    md5sum $filename
else
    echo "$filename cannot be processed"
fi
```

Answer (score 10):

`filename=${1:-/etc/hosts}` assigns value `/etc/hosts` to variable `filename` if `$1` is not set or null.

From [GNU bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

> ```
> ${parameter:-word}
> ```
>
> If `parameter` is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of `parameter` is substituted.

Comment: Which is to say that unless first param $1 sent to it, it wiöl default to /etc/hosts

Comment: @PetterH: No, if you set `$1` to null, `/etc/hosts` is assigned to `filename`.

Comment: @PetterH: I mean, if you try: `./yourscript "" 2 3`, `filename` is set to `/etc/hosts` even if you had **pass** `$1` to script.

Comment: Right you are! I did not concider  that.